# If $\{x_1, x_2\}$ are orthogonal vectors in $\mathbb R^3$, how to prove that we can always find the third vector so that they become orthogonal basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

If $\{x_1, x_2\}$ are orthogonal vectors in $\mathbb R^3$, how to prove that we can always find the third vector so that they become orthogonal basis?

If it is about linear independence, we can just use the theorem to say that it can be enlarged, but for orthogonality, could someone give any ideas?

Comment: For orthogonality you have an other theorem, which is the Gram-Schmidt process. You can get more informations with this link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process

Comment: Use the cross product.

Comment: Assuming that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are nonzero...

Comment: Yes gram-schmidt orthogonalization is the general solution. Cross product would only work on $\mathbb{R}^3$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\pi$ be the orthogonal projection onto $W=\operatorname{span}\{x_1, x_2\}$. Every element of $\ker\pi$ is orthogonal to $W$, and since $\dim W=2$, then $\dim\ker W>0$, so such a nonzero vector exists. Finally, any set of three linearly independent vectors forms a basis for $\mathbb R^3$.